# Scala --- Error when use "[" "]" in parser

Tags: parsing, scala

This is my parser

```
def assstm: Parser[Any] = indexop ~ ":=" ~ expression ~ ";"
def indexop: Parser[Any] = ident ~ "[" ~ expression ~ "]"
```

There is an error with myArray[5] := 5

```
``('' expected but `[' found
```

But with this parser

```
def assstm: Parser[Any] = indexop ~ ":=" ~ expression ~ ";"
def indexop: Parser[Any] = "[" ~ expression ~ "]"
```

And I test with [5] := 5, there is no error.

What is happening?

Comment: The difference is `ident`, so how is `ident` defined?

Comment: @RichardSitze ident is a parser which matches an identifier
`def ident: Parser[String] =
    elem("identifier", _.isInstanceOf[Identifier]) ^^ (_.chars)`

Comment: Post a minimal example that demonstrates the problem that we can actually run.

Answer (score 1):

We need more pieces of your grammar to fully answer your questions. However, it looks like a backtracking issue: you may have defined a rule which tests several alternatives, each using `ident`: one where `ident` must be followed by parens, and your `assstm` rule.

The rule using `ident` and parens may raise an [error](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers%24Error.html) (instead of a [failure](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers%24Failure.html)), aborting the run of your parser.